# Manually invoking modelstate validation fails in nested classes

Tags: c#, validation, model-view-controller

So, I have a class

```
public class Inventory
{
    [Required]
    public Routing Routing { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And, Routing and Items are individual classes with their own validation parameters.

```
public class Routing 
{
    [Required]
    public string SenderId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ReceiverId { get; set; }
    public string PartnerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I was using model validation in web API, it was working just fine.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Inventory request, [FromQuery(Name = "CorrelationId")] string correlationId)
{
    ....
    // Working just fine, validating the incoming request schema as defined by Inventory class
}
```

If user/consumer sends POST request with the wrong schema, it fails at HTTP level and shows 400 BAD Request, and control does not even come inside the `Post` method body. I want the control to come inside `Post` method.

Now, I am doing manual validation

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] string request, [FromQuery(Name = "CorrelationId")] string correlationId)
{
    Inventory obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Inventory>(request);
    var context = new ValidationContext(obj, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, context, validationResults); 

    if (!isValid)
    {
        // Valid even if I omit some parameters of nested classes Routing or Items 
        foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I do, say, omit a `SenderId` from `Routing` class, it is showing Valid in the above manual validation.

What I want:- Schema/Model validation inside the `Post` method, and if invalid, list of all errors inside the `Post` method.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want that design then you have to

1. in your client you need to pass it as a text/plain. example:

> POST /api/values?correlationId=123 HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:5551
>   Content-Type: text/plain cache-control: no-cache Postman-Token:
>   b766b3d6-9478-43b1-b49c-2677e0b08dec {    "routing": {        "senderId":
>   "123",        "receiverId": "456",        "partnerId": "777",         "messageType":
>   "888"     },  "items": [] }

2. in your asp.net core you need to accept text/plain

   public class TextPlainInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
   {
       public TextPlainInputFormatter()
       {
           SupportedMediaTypes.Add("text/plain");
           SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF8EncodingWithoutBOM);
       }

   ```
   protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
   {
       return type == typeof(string);
   }

   public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   {
       string data = null;
       using (var streamReader = context.ReaderFactory(context.HttpContext.Request.Body, encoding))
       {
           data = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
       }
       return InputFormatterResult.Success(data);
   }
   ```

   }
3. add the TextPlainInputFormatter:

   services.AddMvc(options => { options.InputFormatters.Add(new TextPlainInputFormatter()); });